# Magento2 - Error on checkout page while adding Configurable product to cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am using a custom module, where I want to redirect to checkout page once a product is adding to cart. For this I have created an observer `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_index`.

For simple product its working fine. But where I am adding a configurable product it will redirect to checkout page with attribute data so, I am getting an error of noroute on checkout.

Here is my Observer code:

```
 $login_url = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/index/index');

 $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url',$login_url);
```

My error on checkout page because url become like:

```
www.yourDomain.com/checkout/#colors=5431
```

Comment: which error it show to you?

Comment: when I click on checkout button my url displays like this www.yourDomain.com/checkout/noroute/ instead of www.yourDomain.com/checkout/#shipment